# php function adding multiple html lines to variable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a function which contains a table and then loops through data and add rows equal to the loop execution. At the moment it shows an empty page and was wondering what i'm doing wrong in order to return the table? You wont be able to see the result since a backend file is required which is quite big, but i hope someone can see what i'm doing wrong in order to output the table?

```
$url = "http://URL";
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
   $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
   return @curl_exec($ch);
}

function getGames() {

$html = str_get_html(getHTML($url,10));

    //$title = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '',$html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/strong",0)->plaintext);
    //$manuf = $html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong",0)->plaintext;
$table = $html->find("/[@id='matches_list']/",0);

$livescore = "<table class='match-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
$livescore = ."<tbody>";






foreach($table->find("li") as $line){
    $game = $line->find("a/span/img",0)->title;
    if(  $game == "CS:GO" or $game == "Hearthstone" or $game == "Dota 2" or $game == "StarCraft II" or $game == "League of Legends"){

        $opp1 = $line->find("span.opp1",0)->plaintext;
        $opp2 = $line->find("span.opp2",0)->plaintext;
        $score = $line->find("span.score",0)->plaintext;

            $livescore .= "<tr class='margin-tr'>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-icon'>Icon</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-home'>Opp1</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-score'>score</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-away'>opp2</td>";
            $livescore .= "<td class='match-time'>22:00</td>";
            $livescore .= "</tr>";

        }

    }

$livescore = ."</tbody>";
$livescore = ."</table>";

return $livescore;

}


echo getGames();
```

Comment: your $livescore lines.. you do not have any variables.. should not score be $score?

Comment: Would you mind fixing your indents? Also one thing I would usually do to debug is to do some echoing inside the loop.  Also you say "a blank page" do you mean the string is empty or that nothing is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is called getGames() and you try to access it with `echo getGame();`

And

```
$html = str_get_html(getHTML($url,10)); //<<<< $url isn't set
```

Comment: my bad i accidentally deleted it when copying the code. i did use getGames()